# mysql - How to do the SUM() of specific datas depending on 3 tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

A product has different options (attributes), depending on possible options you get product combinations. I want to edit the price of each combinaison for my products. for each combination, price should be equal to the sum of all attributes of this combination.
note: a same attribute can have two different impact on price depending on the product.

I have 3 tables as follow :

> ps_product_attribute_shop - list of attributes with price impact depending of a combination (id_product_attribute).

```
+----------------------+--------+------------+
| id_product_attribute | price  | id_product |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
| 27934                | 50.000 | 9779       |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
| 27935                | 24.000 | 9780       |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
```

> ps_attribute_impact - list of each attributes and the product they belong to and their price impact

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| id_product | id_attribute | price  |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9778       | 45           | 10.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 46           | 00.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 47           | 00.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 55           | 00.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 56           | 46.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 9779       | 57           | 67.000 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

> ps_product_attribute_combination - matching of attributes and product combinations (here the combination 27934 has two attributes => 46, 56)

```
+--------------+----------------------+
| id_attribute | id_product_attribute |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 46           | 27934                |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 56           | 27934                |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 46           | 27935                |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 57           | 27935                |
+--------------+----------------------+
```

I am trying to update all price from `ps_product_attribute_shop` for each product combination.

I try to use the following query in phMyAdmin :

```
UPDATE ps_product_attribute_shop
SET ps_product_attribute_shop.price = 
(
   SELECT SUM(ps_attribute_impact.price) 
   FROM ps_attribute_impact 
   WHERE ps_product_attribute_shop.id_product = ps_attribute_impact.id_product 
         AND ps_attribute_impact.id_attribute IN 
         (
            SELECT ps_product_attribute_combination.id_attribute 
            FROM ps_product_attribute_combination 
            WHERE ps_product_attribute_combination.id_product_attribute = 
                  ps_product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute
         )
);
```

but i got the following error in phpMyAdmin :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: Is that backtick (`) really there?

Comment: Remove `\`` and try

Comment: The error I get is ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ps_attribute_impact.id_attribute' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery' which if memory serves is because this column is too nested. You probably need a multi table update (ie a join) It would me much easier to fix if you provided sample data as text in the question.

Comment: Hi guys,
 1: i don't see any ``` in my code :/
2: @P.Salmon, i'm updating my post to gve more info.

Comment: @Alain.D : I added the backtip by mistake while editing your question (your query is hard to read because it lacks indenting). Sorry about that ! I can see you fixed that (but your query is still to be indented).

Comment: Oh ! my bad thank you GMB for your correction !
@P.Salmon I put more details if it can help =)

Comment: The update query executes ok on my end. No syntax errors.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin when i click "simulate the request" i got the error but when I clicked "execute" it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the following query works.

```
UPDATE ps_product_attribute_shop
SET ps_product_attribute_shop.price = 
(
   SELECT SUM(ps_attribute_impact.price) 
   FROM ps_attribute_impact 
   WHERE ps_product_attribute_shop.id_product = ps_attribute_impact.id_product 
         AND ps_attribute_impact.id_attribute IN 
         (
            SELECT ps_product_attribute_combination.id_attribute 
            FROM ps_product_attribute_combination 
            WHERE ps_product_attribute_combination.id_product_attribute = 
                  ps_product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute
         )
);
```

The problem was when I clicked the "Simulate the request" button in phpMyAdmin. But when I clicked the "Execute" button, all worked properly.

Thank you all for your help.